# How to set reverse proxy using jwilder/nginx-proxy?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set a reverse proxy using **jwilder/nginx-proxy** container.

I have a small Express app:

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/api", (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ hello: "world" });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

and a `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.4"
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - testt

  testt:
    container_name: testt
    image: node:lts
    working_dir: /var/www/html/app/
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=testt.dev # for reverse proxy
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000 # for reverse proxy
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./testt/:/var/www/html/app
    tty: true
    networks:
      - testt

networks:
  testt:
    external: true
```

That is all I have set. Nothing else.

When I run `localhost:3000/api` I get the expected result `{"hello":"world"}`. The same I'd expect to get when I run `http://testt.dev/api` in the browser, but it is not working (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN).

What else do I have to set and where?
Do I have to set something to HOSTS file?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
Docker log:

```
Setting up DH Parameters..

forego      | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000

forego      | starting nginx.1 on port 5100

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: using the "epoll" event method

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: nginx/1.21.3

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6) 

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: OS: Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker processes

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 27

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 28

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 29

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 30

dockergen.1 | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 Template error: open /etc/nginx/certs: no such file or directory

dockergen.1 | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 2 containers

dockergen.1 | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 Running 'nginx -s reload'

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 32, reconfiguring

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: reconfiguring

dockergen.1 | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 Watching docker events

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: using the "epoll" event method

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker processes

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 37

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 38

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 39

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: start worker process 40

dockergen.1 | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 Template error: open /etc/nginx/certs: no such file or directory

dockergen.1 | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 27#27: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 28#28: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 30#30: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 29#29: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 27#27: exiting

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 30#30: exiting

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 29#29: exiting

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 28#28: exiting

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 27#27: exit

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 29#29: exit

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 30#30: exit

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 28#28: exit

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 28

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: worker process 27 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: worker process 28 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 27

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: worker process 30 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 29

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: worker process 29 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2021/12/09 09:39:36 [notice] 22#22: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
```

Comment: Have you set up DNS so `testt.dev` resolves to your machine?

Comment: Anyhow. Do I have to set something to hosts file?

Comment: Yes, that'll work during development. Add `127.0.0.1 testt.dev` to /etc/hosts.

Comment: Well, not working. I'd expect I need to set something like that...but it didn't help. Weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `url` and then `letesencrypt_host` and `letsencrypt_email` if you wants certs. Try:

```
version: '3.7'
services:

    ghost01:
        image: "ghost"
        user: "1000"
        environment:
            - url=https://test01.zathras.io
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=test01.zathras.io
            - VIRTUAL_HOST_ALIAS=test01.zathras.io
            - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=test01.zathras.io
            - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=qdzlug@gmail.com
        networks:
            - webproxy
networks:
    webproxy:
        external: true
```

Comment: Well, I get redirected to the https, but still getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I have added a docker log to my question as well. Thanks

Comment: Hmm okay. The problem is deeper then. The container you're trying to send traffic to isn't running anything as far as can tell. Port 80 I sin an area that you need root access to bind to, so that may be failing as well. If you use the [official nginx image](https://gist.github.com/qdzlug/6c896f06298a33fc3c42827d92cbee2a) to make things work, you can drop this in and it should work fine. 

Take a look at your application, guessing that it's most likely not running. I'd check `docker ps -a` to see if it's running and `docker logs <containerid>` to see what it's logging.